# yii cgridview refresh causes multiple ajax calls

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

Is anyone aware why does yii cgridview refresh button cause multiple ajax calls?

When I refresh, it causes the following ajax calls (this time it's 3 and sometimes it's 4 or 5)

```
GET http://localhost/ijob-css/index.php/activities/d.../activities_id/13/source/iJOB?ajax=sessions-grid

200 OK
        320ms   
jquery.min.js (line 4)
GET http://localhost/ijob-css/index.php/activities/d.../activities_id/13/source/iJOB?ajax=sessions-grid

200 OK
        266ms   
jquery.min.js (line 4)
GET http://localhost/ijob-css/index.php/activities/d.../activities_id/13/source/iJOB?ajax=sessions-grid

200 OK
        262ms   
jquery.min.js (line 4)
```

Sometimes it becomes 4 or 5 ajax calls to the same URL.

But only first time, it works properly I mean refresh happens one time.

Comment: it might be because of some rights; something is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a RenderPartial in your controller in which you are running this code? If so, I suggest that you look for the scriptMap in Yii that prevents jQuery from running everytime this controller is used.

```php
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array(
                    'jquery.js'=>false,
                    'jquery.yiigridview.js'=>false
                );
```

I had the same problem before. I encountered this in gridviews and other views that have an ajax action in it. Hope this helps.